# How to increase default maximum number of rows in Astyanax?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

Hi I am using Astyanax client to access Cassandra with CQL inside my program. The problem I'm having is that when I execute a query the number of rows of the OperationResult is set to a maximum of 10 000. I need to increase this limit for my needs. Pagination cannot be done when using CQL with Astyanax. If anybody could point me into a right direction that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astyanax, when using CQL, does not limit how many rows are returned.
You may want to check your Cassandra configuration.
I would warn that returning too many rows may cause other issues at the client level, like running out of memory.

Cheers

Comment: Hey Christos can you tell me how to set the default max no rows using cassandra configuration???

Answer (score 2):

It is in the query the default limit is 10000 you need to specify the limit within the query.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/SELECT

has the answer